# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Async plugin executed by System User

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, impersonation

I have two plugins registered in the plugin registration tool. Both plugins have "**calling user**" at the "Run at users context" value.

1. the first plugin has a step registered on post update of Entity X (Async)
2. the second plugin has a step registered on the retrievemultiple of products (Sync)

The first plugin retrieves products, so it triggers the second plugin. When I check the **context.UserId** property of the first plugin, I find the userId of the logged in user. But in the second plugin, the property is set to the **SYSTEM users**'s Guid.

I'm using the following code to instatiate the organisationService in both plugins:

```
    this.OrganizationService = 
factory.CreateOrganizationService(this.PluginExecutionContext.UserId);
```

Any idea what is going on? Why is the second plugin not executed by the logged in user?

EDIT:

When I look in the system jobs tracing I find the following ID's:

Plugin 1 (Async):

```
context.Initiating User: Logged in user
context.User: SYSTEM
```

Plugin 2 (Sync):

```
context.Initiating User ID: SYSTEM
context.User ID: SYSTEM
```

It does make sense that the Async service user (SYSTEM) triggers plugin 2, so Context.UserId in Plugin 2 is actually the SYSTEM users Guid.

Actually what I'm trying to do (in pseudo-code) is something like this (in plugin 1):

```
context.UserId = context.InitiatingUserId
```

But the problem with this is that context.UserId is a read-only property.

Any ideas how to enfore something like this?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but i believe you cannot en-force the initiating user id, as the system sets this. You can try to initiate a new retrieveMultipleRequest setting the user you require and ignore first one. Provide more info on your problem as to why you would like to do this, maybe there will be another workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I don't want plugin 2 (a Multi-language plugin) to trigger. I only want to update a product async. So I don't need the translation .

The way I worked around this problem is adding the SYTEM user Guid in the unsecure config and check if it's the system user or another user executing the plugin. If it's the system, stop the execution of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To impersonate in a plugin based on your code above, do something like this:

```
((OrganizationServiceProxy)this.OrganizationService).CallerId = loggedInUserId;
```